# Full height main div in dash

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I have created a very simple dash application, but I cannot get the main div to stretch to the full page height.

Here is the python code

```py
import dash
from dash import html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
page = html.Div(id='page',
                children=[html.H1('hello')],
                style={'background-color': 'orange', 'height': '100%', 'width': '100%'},
                className='flex-grow-1')

app.layout = html.Div(
    page,
    className='full-screen-div'
)

app.run_server()
```

Here is the css code under `assets/custom.css`

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.full-screen-div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

The page looks as shown below - I would like the orange background to stretch to fill the browser window.
I have tried setting height with the viewport height parameter, but that doesn't translate well between screen sizes. I have also tried setting `position: fixed`, but that gives some overflow when introducing figures.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional `<div>` that needs to be expanded, change your first CSS block to include `#react-entry-point`:

```css
body, html, #react-entry-point {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

**Result:**
[image]

That white spacing at the top is due to `margin` on the `<h1>`, if you want to remove that, consider [resetting browser styling](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+reset+browser+default+styles) or add the following:

```css
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Result:**
[image]